# Springboot, save message from pubsub with hibernate and jpa create primary key constraint violation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to acheive a simple scenario : I receive a message from pubsub in my application, and I want to save it into DB. The point I can receive two message with the same id, some the second message should update the data, but I get a primary violation.
In the sql log I have

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        batch0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        batch0_.date as date2_0_0_,
        batch0_.message as message3_0_0_,
        batch0_.status as status4_0_0_,
        batch0_.type as type5_0_0_ 
    from
        batch batch0_ 
    where
        batch0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        batch0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        batch0_.date as date2_0_0_,
        batch0_.message as message3_0_0_,
        batch0_.status as status4_0_0_,
        batch0_.type as type5_0_0_ 
    from
        batch batch0_ 
    where
        batch0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        batch
        (date, message, status, type, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        batch
        (date, message, status, type, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

It seems hibernate make a select to check if the id exist for the 1st and 2nd message before the insert !!

The message arrives in my spring service with the basic example from spring

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubCheckConsistencyChannel")
public void messageReceiver(
      String payload,
      @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
    log.info("Message arrived on pubSubCheckConsistencyChannel Payload: " + payload);
    try {
      var batch = getBatchFromMessage(payload);
      saveBatch(batch);
      log.info("message  {} saved:", batch.getId());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      log.error("error when try to read json message", e);
    } finally {
      message.ack();
    }
}
```

The message are saved by

```
@Transactional
public void saveBatch(Batch batch) {
batchCacheManager.getCache("batch").put(batch.getId(), batchMapper.toDTO(batch));
  batchRepository.saveAndFlush(batch);
}

My repository is defined as

@Repository
public interface BatchRepository extends JpaRepository<Batch, UUID>
```

My entity is defined by

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Batch  {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid",name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @ToString.Include
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;
```

I guess it's due to multithreading, how can wait the message is finished to taking into account the service activator or synchronized the insert ?
Thank for your help

Comment: Ok, I fix it by settings limit the connection pool to 1 connection active.  1 is not a big deal because, I just have a table and manage db for this channel. I guess, I could also register message with auto increment key, but that not the same datamodel. Or may be have a taskExecutor for queue.  I wonder what is the best pratice to this kind of use case ?

Comment: Add change the process to store all messages, and have asynchronous process to update the destination table taking into account all the receive messages